# String Operation

Tags: iphone, cocoa, nsstring

If there is an NSString like "com.mycompany.purchase1" How to get only purchase1.

```
NSString *mainString = @"com.mycompany.purchase1";

-(NSString*)getLastComponent : (NSString*) mainString
{
NSString *string;
//Implementation
return string;//It should return only "purchase1"
}
```

I tried using lastPathComponent,pathExtension and also i can't use substringToIndex since the string may be of varying length.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't want donkim's answer as he is correct. Just showing the implementation I would use

```
-(NSString*)lastComponentOfString:(NSString*)string separatedByString:(NSString*)separator
{
    return [[string componentsSeparatedByString:separator] lastObject];
}
```

Use

```
NSString *string = @"com.mycompany.purchase1";
[... lastComponentOfString:string separatedByString:@"."];
```

Comment: +1 ok then this is the built in function for finding last component in string.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `- (NSArray *)componentsSeparatedByString:(NSString *)separator` method in `NSString`. Check to see that `NSArray` has a count greater than 0 and the last component of it (`[array objectAtIndex:[array count] - 1]`) will be what you want.

Comment: if you just use `lastObject` on the returned `NSArray`, it will automatically return `nil` if the array is empty.  Convenient! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
-(NSString*)getLastComponent : (NSString*) mainString
{
  NSString *string1;

  NSArray *arr=[mainString componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
  string1=[arr objectAtIndex:([arr count]-1)];
  return string;
}
```

use above code.